# scp only creates a local file, does not copy to linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have a raspberry pi set up for a class, that I am supposed to use to access a Linux server on campus.  I can SSH into the server completely fine.  When I'm using the command line locally, however, I can't scp a file from my local machine to the server.  As according to my teacher, I should use:

```
scp <Path-to-File> <Logname>@servername.school.edu
```

He notes that if I my local username is the same as that of my username on the server, then I don't need to include the Logname.  Either way that I've tried, and when using `sudo`, it only creates a file in the `/home/username` folder named the same as the server address i.e. `/home/username/<Logname>@servername.school.edu.txt`.

The pi and the server are on the same network, and other users in my class have been able to do this successfully.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scp <Path-to-File> <Logname>@servername.school.edu:
```

The last argument is `user@server:/remote/path`. You can omit `/remote/path` but it's the colon (`:`) that informs `scp` the argument is not a local filename.

On the other hand if you ever need `scp` to treat `user@server:` as a local filename containing a colon, make it a (full or relative) path, like `./user@server:`.